# How to make this problem convex and solve it using CVX?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matlab, cvx

How to make this problem convex so that it can be solved by semidefinite programming in cvx? Given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X\in\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}}{\text{maximize}} & \frac{\mathrm{trace}\big((A^*A+I)X\big)}{\mathrm{trace}\big((A+A^*)X\big)}.\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm{trace}\big((A-A^*)X\big)=0,\\&\mathrm{trace}(X)=1,\\&X\geq0.\end{array}

---

I have tried to let $\mathrm{trace}\big((A+A^*)X\big)=1/k$, so that I can rewrite above problem as

\begin{array}{ll} \underset{X\in\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}, k\in\mathbb{R}}{\text{maximize}} & k\times\mathrm{trace}\big((A^*A+I)X\big).\\ \text{subject to} & k\times\mathrm{trace}\big((A+A^*)X\big)=1\\&\mathrm{trace}\big((A-A^*)X\big)=0,\\&\mathrm{trace}(X)=1,\\&X\geq0.\end{array}

CVX code from Matlab:

```
    n=length(A);
    A1=A'*A+eye(n,n);
    A2=0.5*(A+A'); 
    A3=0.5*(A-A'); 

    cvx_begin
    variable X(n,n) hermitian
    variable k 
    minimize(-k*trace(A1*X));
    subject to
    k*trace(A2*X)==1;
    trace(A3*X)==0;
    trace(X)==1;
    X == hermitian_semidefinite(n);
```

ERROR code:

```
Error using  .*  (line 262)
Disciplined convex programming error:
    Invalid quadratic form(s): not a square.


Error in  *  (line 36)
    z = feval( oper, x, y );

Error in QCQP_SDR_GM (line 11)
minimize(-k*trace(A1*X));
```

Comment: "CVX for the dumbs" [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/hall/NATCOR_2014/Intro_to_cvx.pdf)

Comment: You could try making $k$ a parameter of the problem and not a variable. You can then solve it for a range of $k$ and see what is optimal.